# What is a word that would describe some who is strong yet is not afraid of showing his/her emotions to others?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm trying to describe someone who is mentally and physically strong, but who is also able to show his/her tender side and emotions.

Comment: Could you please give us an example sentence with a blank space for the missing word?

Comment: Why are you using the word **yet**, as if strength is contradictory to the expression of emotion?

Comment: Not sure about what word would describe that quality but it is a sign of high EQ

Comment: Why do you think a word with this combination of three different meanings exists? Have you been told that there is an English word that means exactly this? Or is there a word in your native language? Is there a reason why you can't just use the phrase "He was mentally and physically strong, and unafraid to show his emotions."

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single word that describes that combination of qualities, at least that I can think of as a native speaker of American English.

It is perfectly fine to describe it the way you have already:

> strong yet not afraid to show his or her emotions.

As mentioned in the comments, the use of the word 'yet' would show that you thought it was a contradiction to be both at once. If you didn't want to express that opinion you could say

> strong and not afraid to show emotion

Some other options would be

> strong and sensitive
>   strong, with a high degree of emotional intelligence and awareness
>   strong physically, mentally and emotionally

In this case English is like a language that doesn't have a word for 'orange'. You would have to say 'red like the setting sun'.